# Return exception from proxy

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm using the heavily-undocumented Castle dynamic-proxy system. I've managed to make it do almost everything I want, except for one thing: How do you make a proxied method throw an exception instead of returning a value?

```
public sealed class MyInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
  public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
  {
    if (CheckArgs(invocation.Arguments))
    {
      invocation.ReturnValue = DoRealWork(invocation.Arguments);
    }
    else
    {
      invocation.Exception = new InvalidOperationException(); // How?
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point of view of the proxied object the interceptor is not visible; it simply calls its own virtual method, and DynamicProxy invokes the correct interceptor methods before returning the `ReturnValue` to the caller.

So if you want to throw an exception just throw it from the interceptor:

```
if (CheckArgs(invocation.Arguments))
{
  invocation.ReturnValue = DoRealWork(invocation.Arguments);
}
else
{
  throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

From the point of view of the caller it will be an exception in the called method.

**Edit for comment**:

Regarding the type of the exception thrown in the generator I have the correct type, not a wrapper:

```
public interface IDummy
{
    string DoSomething();
}

public class Dummy: IDummy {
    public virtual string DoSomething()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public class MyCustomException : Exception {}

public class CustomIntercept: IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        throw new MyCustomException();
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pg = new ProxyGenerator();
        GetValue(pg.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<IDummy>(new CustomIntercept()));
        GetValue(pg.CreateClassProxy<Dummy>(new CustomIntercept()));
        GetValue(pg.CreateClassProxyWithTarget<Dummy>(new Dummy(), new CustomIntercept()));
        GetValue(pg.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<IDummy>(new Dummy(), new CustomIntercept()));
    }

    private static void GetValue(IDummy dummy)
    {
        try
        {
            dummy.DoSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

All four outputs are `MyCustomException`

Can you make sure that the TargetInvocationException doesn't come from your own code? What version of the DynamicProxy are you using (I'm using the one in Castle.Core 3.2)

Comment: This does work, but it gives me `TargetInvocationException` rather than the `InvalidOperationException` that the code is expecting to catch.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I just checked, I have the correct exception type. Please see edit

Comment: When I run your example code, I get the same result. Now I'm puzzled as to why the hell it doesn't work in my actual application. Hmm...

Comment: OK, I figured it out: Castle is throwing exactly the exception I told it to throw. The problem is that the exception is getting wrapped somewhere else, before it even gets passed to the interceptor. Nothing to do with Castle.