# Can a mock be configured to throw a specified exception on any method call?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have an interface which can't be modified and has a ridiculous amount of methods (basically overloads--each is slightly different).

In some scenarios every method on the interface should throw the same exception.  There are several of these scenarios, each with their own exception (stuff like `SystemInMaintenanceModeException`, `ClientRateLimitedException`, `TheJanitorUnpluggedTheServerException`).

There are unit tests and the amount of setup for these exception-throwing scenarios feels downright silly...  something like:

```cs
_mockedService.Setup(mock => mock.DoA(It.IsAny<string>()).Throws(expectedException);
_mockedService.Setup(mock => mock.DoB(It.IsAny<string>()).Throws(expectedException);
_mockedService.Setup(mock => mock.DoC(It.IsAny<string>()).Throws(expectedException);
...
_mockedService.Setup(mock => mock.DoX(It.IsAny<string>()).Throws(expectedException);
_mockedService.Setup(mock => mock.DoY(It.IsAny<string>()).Throws(expectedException);
_mockedService.Setup(mock => mock.DoZ(It.IsAny<string>()).Throws(expectedException);
```

Can Moq be configured to throw a specified exception for every method on the mocked interface?

PS: I'm aware that the Strict behavior will throw an exception on any call, but I need it to be specified exception(s).

Comment: PPS: the above example is contrived -- if Moq can just throw a specified exception it really is the best option

Answer (score 2):

Moq uses Castle DynamicProxy, so you could use it directly like this

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;

public class Interceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        }
    }

    public interface ITest
    {
        void Test1();
        Task Test2(string a);
        int Add(int a1, int a2);
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
                var c = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<ITest>(new Interceptor());
                try
                {
                    var r = c.Add(11, 22);

                    Console.WriteLine(r);
                }
                catch (NotImplementedException e)
                {

                }
                c.Test2("");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319909/return-exception-from-proxy)

For Task returning methods you would probably need extra logic like to return Task.FromException.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using FakeItEasy, it has great support for this scenario:

```
A.CallTo(_service).Throws(expectedException)
```

This will make any method on the mock throw the specified exception.

https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specifying-a-call-to-configure/#specifying-a-call-to-any-method-or-property

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way to do this in Moq that I know of. Built in support would be via  `DefaultValueProvider`, but that'll only work for methods that return a value.

```
public class DefaultException : DefaultValueProvider
{
    protected override object GetDefaultValue(Type type, Mock mock)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("asdf");
    }
}

...

var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
fooMock.DefaultValueProvider = new DefaultException();
var foo = fooMock.Object;
            
Invoking(() => foo.Bar()).Should().Throw<InvalidOperationException>("asdf");
```

I've used `IInterceptor` as mentioned in a another answer here and it'll work as described. My usage was over the `Mock<T>` itself so required a bit more care, but over the target interface directly should present nothing unusual.

Holistically this feels like a problem that AutoMoq could solve, with some customisation around the method set up. I couldn't find a ready made solution but it'd be what I'd look into if I wanted a pure solution to the problem.